# Шаринг Youtube видео в блоге

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем простейшее приложение блога. Есть ли готовые гемы для добавления youtube видео в запись блога? Например, чтобы когда пользователь создает новую запись, он мог просто вставить ссылку ютуб видео. А скрипт уже сконвертил эту ссылку в iframe

Comment: Поставил минус, поскольку не считаю полезным. Выбор редактора для приложения это очень обширный вопрос. Добавление Youtube-видео это лишь один из критериев, причём довольно мелкий (у многих редакторов есть API, позволяющий это добавить). Сейчас вас интересует только видео, потом заинтересует что-то ещё... а ещё в этой области много коммерческих решений, рассказ о которых здесь будет на грани рекламы. Я бы скорее на вашем месте выбрал конкретный редактор (и плагины, возможно) и спросил, как его интегрировать в Rails (как добавить ассеты, написать хелпер, обновлять...), это было бы полезно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Могли бы вы посоветовать один из лучших редакторов на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Да, [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) :) Но что нравится мне, вряд ли понравится вам и вашим пользователям.